# Limit of integrable Fn is integrable , lim ∫Fn = ∫F

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I posted a (apparently wrong) proof  to this before but this proof feels better.

Let X be a finite measure space.
Let (integrable) Fn converge uniformly to F

Then F is integrable and lim ∫Fn = ∫F

Proof:

Since Fn are integrable, they only equal infinite on a null set, replace Fn with Gn, where Gn = Fn but bounded on the null sets , then since Gn is bounded and converges uniformly to F, it is uniformly bounded by a constant M.
So   |Fn|<|M| , hence we can use the domination theorem and the result follows.

Comment: To keep uniform convergence define $G_n$ to be zero on the sets $E_n$ where $F_n$ are infinite. Redefine also $F$ on the limit ($\cup_{n>0}\cap_{m>n}E_m$) of those sets to be zero too.

Comment: Also, being equal to infinity is not the only way to be unbounded. The functions $G_n$ could be finite everywhere and still unbounded. For example $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: What is $M$? (the problems are deeper than this but let's start there)

Comment: Finish this: For $\epsilon>0$ there is $M$ such that if $n>M$ then

$$|F|-|F_n|\leq|F_n(x)-F(x)|<\epsilon,\text{ for all }x\in X$$

So, $|F(x)|\leq \epsilon + |F_n(x)|$ for all $x\in X$ and $n>M$.

Comment: I am pretty sure the function I put above is very integrable and is unbounded. But maybe you are right if your "integrable" is just Riemann integrable

Comment: now that you've edited to say $M$ is a constant I will reply that no, it does not follow that $G_n$ is bounded by a constant. As bettybel indicated the function we are converging to could be integrable but unbounded. I suppose this proof is less wrong than your last but you should take a lesson from the fact that two different people found your two questions on this and both answered with the same short proof. You are missing the central idea yet remain oddly preoccupied with irrelevant details about the null sets.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Am trying to find a more intuitive solution but your right, I need to move on...

Comment: Sorry if that was blunt. They way I'd put it is that I think if you work on understanding how that proof works rather than trying to make a new one, it will become intuitive, and you will have improved intuition going forward. And once you do you will see there is in fact an alternative proof the shows a dominating function and uses dct.